# Web API without DTO: POCOs have strange value for navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a Web API application; I'm using EF 5.0 and POCO Classes autogenerated with the  VS2012 template. Lazy loading and proxy generation are disabled.

When my objects are serialized I find that navigation properties are included in the JSON output, and valued with 'null'.

When my object are deserialized (ie: for a "save" action) these navigation properties are not valued with 'null', but with an empty istance of the object.

Here is an example of the serialization:

```
 [{"EmployeeTimeblockId":1,"EmployeeId":1,"DayOfWeek":0, "StartDate":"2012-05-    27T00:00:00", "EndDate":"2012-09- 02T00:00:00", "StartTime":"16:00:00","EndTime":"18:00:00","Notes":"null","Employee":null}]
```

When I send back this object, with the "Employee" field still null, the deserializer changes its value with a  new Employee()  istance. This is a problem because Entity Framework obviously tries to attach this object and I don't want this behaviour.

My workaround is to do manually set my object navigation properties to null, as in:

```
        var uow = new Infrastructure.Database.UnitOfWork();
        var rep = uow.EmployeeTimeblockRepository;
        e.Employee = null;
        rep.Update(e);
        uow.Save();
```

But this is not an elegant solution. Any suggestion on how I can get clean deserialized object, without using DTOs?

Thanks,
Nicola

Comment: I just started thinking DTO when I read your last sentence. Why without? Admitted, all these DTO classes drive me nuts sometimes, but at least they never do anything I don't tell them to do.

Comment: I'm not using DTO because I'm developing an app which is just a bit more than a prototype. So my primary goal is to have a fast delivery time.
(I was thinking I could use automapper and a simplified T4 template to autogenerate my DTOs...)

Comment: My experience is that prototypes have a way of evolving into the real thing. Better do things right from the outset (saves tons of refactoring and redesign later). If you already know AutoMapper, use it. T4 template for DTO's hardly ever produces DTO's that are dedicated to a specific job. Further, with Json using dynamic objects can be a very good choice. With javascript/json there is always a boundary between "typed" and "untyped" environments. Using dynamic objects only moves that boundary a bit.